# How can I get stub files for `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, etc.?

Tags: python, stub, mypy

I know that the stub files for built-in Python library for type checking and static analysis come with `mypy` or PyCharm installation. How can I get stub files for `matplotlib`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, etc.?

Comment: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#library-stubs-and-typeshed, they come from https://pypi.org/project/typeshed/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Awesome! This really helps!

Comment: The packages you mentioned are not contained in `typeshed`. For `numpy`, there is an official [stub project](https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs) and can be installed via e.g. `pip install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs`. For `pandas` etc, there are no official type hints yet, but lots of unofficial projects available, e.g. [`data-science-types`](https://pypi.org/project/data-science-types/).

Comment: @hoefling This is great information. Thank you very much!

Comment: If anyone wonders in 2021, scipy is now typed since 1.5 release

Comment: @krassowski I have scipy 1.6.0, but mypy doesn't find its type stubs yet.

Comment: I submitted [a bug for `fxpmath`](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath/issues/94) which does not appear to have any such "types" package.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Type stubs are sometimes packaged directly with the library. Otherwise there can be some external libraries to provide them.

### Numpy

Starting with numpy 1.20 type stubs will be included in numpy. See this [changelog](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#numpy-is-now-typed) and this [PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/16515) adding them

Before that they could added with the library https://github.com/numpy/numpy-stubs

### Pandas and Matplotlib

For pandas, official stub support can be found in the [pandas-stubs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/) repository, which is the official pandas stubs project.

There is no official support for stubs in Matplotlib, but you can check for community-contributed stubs or create your own if needed.

In some cases, you might also find unofficial stubs in projects like [data-science-types](https://pypi.org/project/data-science-types/), but for the most up-to-date and reliable stubs, it's recommended to use the official sources mentioned above.

Comment: How can I install numpy 1.20 now?

Comment: It's not released yet, here is the milestone on github to follow the progress: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/milestone/83

Comment: The data-science-types repo has been archived, and development has stopped.

Comment: `pandas-stubs`: https://pypi.org/project/pandas-stubs/

Comment: I am using numpy 1.23.5, but why does mypy still complain about "cannot find implementation or library stub for module named numpy"?

Answer (score 14):

As of July 2022 there are official pandas stubs: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs

> This is the home for pandas typing stubs supported by the pandas core team. The stubs are likely incomplete in terms of covering the published API of pandas.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using VSCode and Pylance extension with strict type checking enabled, you can generate stub files automatically by just pressing quickfix option and press "Create Type Stub for "*module*" "

[image]