# Type hint for matplotlib axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.8, plot-annotations

I'm writing type annotations for some functions and I couldn't find the best way to annotate an argument which is expected to be of type `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes`.

I'm not even sure if I'm doing the right thing for an argument expected to be of type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

```
def myfunc(
        df: pd.DataFrame, # is this correct?
        ax: matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes # do I have to use this?
        ) -> None:
   
    # body of my function
```

Some insights?

Thanks.

Comment: To alleviate some of the pain of typing it out you could do the following: `from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes as MplAxes` and then just use `ax: MplAxes` as the typehint, also it seems that the following should be valid (is for me on a somewhat recent matplotlib): `matplotlib.axes.Axes` (see https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html) which seems pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reference the `.pyi` file in the typehint, just use the actual class name. Your IDE or `mypy` will figure it out.

If you want `mypy` to work with matplotlib version <3.8 you will need [`data-science-types`](https://pypi.org/project/data-science-types/). `data-science-types` only needs to be installed, not imported.

See [this matplotlib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20504). Related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247157/how-can-i-get-stub-files-for-matplotlib-numpy-scipy-pandas-etc).

The following has been tested with `mypy` after running `pip install data-science-types`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.axes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def myfunc(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    ax: matplotlib.axes.Axes,
) -> None:
    ax.plot(df.values.mean(), df.values.std())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f, axis = plt.subplots()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50, 10))
    myfunc(df, axis)
```

Running `mypy` returns `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

Comment: removes the matplotlib Axes problem, but now complains about accessing values from every data frame in the repo I'm working on, and about a million other things... :(