# How to type-hint a matplotlib Figure object in Python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, type-hinting

I am trying to add type hints for data returned by plt.subplots.
That works fine for plt.Axes, but I can't seem to find a solution for Figure.

Any ideas what I could do?

An abbreviated version of my code is:

```
def draw_graph() -> Tuple[plt.Figure, plt.Axes]: 

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10))
    return (fig, ax)
```

I get the message: "Figure" is not a known member of module Pylance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get stub files for \`matplotlib\`, \`numpy\`, \`scipy\`, \`pandas\`, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247157/how-can-i-get-stub-files-for-matplotlib-numpy-scipy-pandas-etc)

Comment: unfortunately, that did not get me very far. 
data-science-types has been archived and does not contain Figure anyway.

Comment: The main point was this: _"There is no official support for these libraries stubs"_. Unfortunately, you'll have to try and find third-party stubs, write your own stubs (as you need them), or make exceptions in your annotations (e.g. via `type: ignore`) in places that rely on matplotlib types. That library seems to come from a time, when annotating Python modules was uncommon (or maybe even impossible) and by now it is so extremely bloated that adding correct type annotations throughout it would be a giant project in itself. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20504

Comment: That was more or less my conclusion as well. So what I did was to add `# type ignore` comments to the offending lines. Not really satisfying, but it seems the best I can do...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest Matplotlib (v3.7.1) I was able to do the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure

def draw_graph() -> Tuple[matplotlib.figure.Figure, plt.Axes]: 

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,10))
    return (fig, ax)
```

I haven't tested using `plt.Figure`, but my IDE (i.e., VS Code) was not giving me any errors with `plt.Figure`.

Comment: I had to change the second line to
`import matplotlib.figure`.

Then it seems to work for me.

Comment: You're right, I had to use import `matplotlib.figure` as well for another environment I was using. Thanks for the recommendation, I've updated the answer response to reflect the better solution.