# How to type hint results of specific function calls with generic return signature

Tags: python, type-hinting, pyright

I believe it is easier to ask this question using a concrete example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


_, ax = plt.subplots()
# Pyright: Cannot access member "plot" for type "ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]]"  
# Member "plot" is unknown
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1])

plt.show()
```

The code above runs as expected, but the static type checker (I am using Pyright) has trouble figuring out the type of `ax`. The problem is that the return type of `plt.subplots` depends on its arguments (and possibly on the context it is being used), so its return signature is rather general, i.e.
`tuple[FigureBase | Unknown, Any | ndarray[Any, dtype[Any]] | Unknown]`.

However, in this particular case I know that the result is expected to be of type `tuple[plt.Figure, plt.Axes]`. So I guess the question is what is the way to declare this in the code, so that the static type checker can reason about `ax.plot`?

Comment: I believe there is no way to avoid the warning by pyright about unknown type of the library, a solution is just typehint as you wish and if you know the type is going to be correct add at the end of the warning line `# typeignore: Your[ERROR]`

Comment: another thing you could try is to import the stubfiles

Comment: @Axeltherabbit. 1) The problem with ignoring the type is that I will be giving up on functionalities such as auto-completion, which would be otherwise available on many IDEs. 2) can you explain more about importing the stubfiles? Is it advisable for code that is shared with other devs?

Comment: stub files can just help fix some typing for libraries that you import, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247157/how-can-i-get-stub-files-for-matplotlib-numpy-scipy-pandas-etc